# Rsync for filenames with wildcard characters

Tags: rsync

`Ubuntu 12.04, rsync version 3.0.9 protocol version 30`. Using `rsync` to copy and delete files `rsync -qaz --remove-source-files /source/* /mydir/`

Some of my files have the wildcard character, *, in them and is causing rsync to throw an error if used with `--remove-source-files` option

```
rsync: mkstemp "/mydir/.foo#2.20.2[2.20.2*]#bar.lz.xml.3mebWw" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

I have tried `-s, --protect-args` without success. If I use `rsync` to only copy files, it works just fine. Does anyone know to handle this?

Comment: It works for me when I created a file with that name, on Ubuntu 14.04 (rsync 3.1.0). You need to post your whole command line, and what rsync versions the local and remote hosts have.

Comment: Thanks for trying, see updated question for answers to your questions. Wondering if this could be an Ubuntu 12.04 issue.

Comment: I don't have 12.04 to test, but my guess is you found an rsync bug that has since been fixed.